# Javascript Onclick Function not working when Toggling Temperature

Tags: javascript, function, api, weather-api

I'm working on a weather api and I'm having trouble toggling between Celsius and Fahrenheit.

I used a separate function to get the location as well as call from the API.

I also added an onclick function within this second function. I can get it to toggle to one temperature but not back.

```
function getTemp(data) {
  // API variables
  var temp1 = data.main.temp;
  var weatherUrl = data.weather[0].icon;
  var tempInC = Math.round(temp1); // Temp in Celsius
  var tempInF = Math.round(temp1 * 9/5 +32)

  // Inner HTML variables
  var weatherF = "The weather is " + tempInF + " &#8457; <br>" +
     "<img src='" + weatherUrl + "'/>";
  var weatherC = "The weather is " + tempInC + " &#8451; <br>" +
     "<img src='" + weatherUrl + "'/>";

  // Button DOM variables
  var buttonText = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].innerText;
  var buttonId = document.getElementById('btn');
  x.innerHTML = weatherF;

  buttonId.onclick = function toggleTemp() {
    if(buttonText == "Convert to Celsius") {
       x.innerHTML = weatherC; 
     buttonId.innerText = "Convert to Fahrenheit";
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = weatherF;
      buttonId.innerText = "Convert to Celsius";
    }
  }
}
```

I used *innerText* because I thought it was the easiest way to toggle back and forth between temp. I can get the weather to convert to Celsius, but the else statement is not working. Fyi, I was not able to get the button text to change using the tag name which is why I resorted to using an *id* in the button click function. I'm still pretty new at Javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to set `buttonText` inside the `onclick` function, so it will get the current text.

Comment: Or just use `if (buttonId.innerText == "Convert to Celcius")`

Comment: Actually, it's confusing. You set `buttonText` from `document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]`, but `buttonId = document.getElementById('btn');`. Why are you testing the text of one, but changing the text of the other?

Comment: Your second reply worked! You're right, it is confusing. I got caught up in not being able to change the text using the getElementsByTagName instead of evaluating it in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `buttonText` variable when you toggle the text of `buttonId`.

```js
buttonId.onclick = function toggleTemp() {
  if (buttonText == "Convert to Celsius") {
    x.innerHTML = weatherC;
    buttonText = buttonId.innerText = "Convert to Fahrenheit";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = weatherF;
    buttonText = buttonId.innerText = "Convert to Celsius";
  }
}
```

Comment: That didn't anything when I clicked the button. The original one where you said to change the if conditional to *buttonId.innerText == "Convert to Celsius" was the one that worked.

Comment: It should work either way. Since the code sets `buttonText` to the same thing as `buttonId.innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `x` is undefined. In the future, try to avoid using the `innerHTML` property, which can break event listeners and be slow to render.

Neither `buttonText` nor `x` are defined in the scope of your `onclick` function, which might be why nothing happens. Have you checked the console for errors?

```
function getTemp(data) {
    // API variables
    var temp1 = data.main.temp;
    var weatherUrl = data.weather[0].icon;
    var tempInC = Math.round(temp1); // Temp in Celsius
    var tempInF = Math.round(temp1 * 9/5 +32)

    // Inner HTML variables
    var weatherF = "The weather is " + tempInF + " &#8457; <br>" +
        "<img src='" + weatherUrl + "'/>";
    var weatherC = "The weather is " + tempInC + " &#8451; <br>" +
        "<img src='" + weatherUrl + "'/>";

    // Button DOM variables
    var x = ...;  // Declare x for the function scope here
    var buttonText = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].innerText;
    var buttonId = document.getElementById('btn');
    x.innerHTML = weatherF;

    buttonId.onclick = (function (x, wC, wF, btn) {
        return function () {
            // Change DOM
            if(btn.innerText == "Convert to Celsius") {
                x.innerHTML = wC; 
                btn.innerText = "Convert to Fahrenheit";
            } else {
                x.innerHTML = wF;
                btn.innerText = "Convert to Celsius";
            }
        };
    })(x, weatherC, weatherF, document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0])
}
```

Comment: `buttonText` is in the scope of the `onclick` function, it's inherited from the `getTemp()` function's scope.

Comment: @Barmar Ah geez. I'm too used to using callbacks in async JS.

Comment: Okay, x is a variable in the global scope that is used to add to call the element that places the actual weather on the page.